# Django how to use webhook and post data?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, webhooks, zapier

i am confused about django webhooks because i am beginner in python and django. Most of the things i see for the documentation. how do i connect to my app and Post data.Can anyone tell me how do i set my webhook for my data.
i want to Post data to zapier.

**Models.py**

```
class Driver(models.Model):
    class Meta():
        db_table = "driver"
        verbose_name = "Driver"
        verbose_name_plural = "Drivers"
        ordering = ['driver_firstname', 'driver_lastname']

    driver_firstname = models.CharField(
        max_length=64,
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )
    driver_lastname = models.CharField(
        max_length=64,
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )

    driver_email= models.CharField(
        max_length=64,
        blank=True,
        null=True

    )
```

**Views.py**

```
def drivers(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.POST['driver_firstname'] and request.POST['driver_lastname'] and request.POST['driver_email']
            driver = Driver()
            driver.driver_firstname = request.POST['driver_firstname']
            driver.driver_lastname = request.POST['driver_lastname']
            driver.driver_email = request.POST['driver_email']
            driver.save()
```

Comment: This is unclear. Are you trying to post data *to* Zapier, or get Zapier to post to you? What is wrong with the code you have shown?

Comment: i want to post data to zapier excel sheets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to post data outside of your app, you can take a look to HTTP library [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/)

For example:

```
import requests

driver_firstname = request.POST['driver_firstname']
driver_lastname = request.POST['driver_lastname']
driver_email = request.POST['driver_email']

payload = {'driver.driver_firstname': driver_firstname,
           'driver.driver_lastname': driver_lastname,
           'driver.driver_email': driver_email
           }

r = requests.post("http://your-url.org/post", data=payload)
```

Comment: hi can i ask you further questions Sir >

Comment: Yes sure, for that, open a new question and just mention me to let me know.

If this question is closed, you can validate the good answer.

Comment: when i am posting its not sending the data like in form i use driver_firstname =John . and in spreedsheet its saving driver_firstname rather then sending the John to driver _firstname

Comment: I have edited my snippet. You just have to remove the quotes to pass the variables as well.

Comment: thankyou so much @Aurelien . can you upvote my question also

Comment: thankyou . i am newbie can you tell me wwhere to start learning about advanced django

Comment: You can see websites like Treehouse or Udemy.